# Scroll horizontally across image thumbnails and have images pop up on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, css, html, hover, overflow

I have written some code in html and css to scroll horizontally across image thumbnails and have them pop up on mouse hover. The problem is that when I can scroll horizontally, then the popped up (enlarged) image on mouse hover is only visible within the div that it is contained in. I would like for it to be visible on top of everything else on the page. But since I created the scroll bar by making the property of the div overflow-x:scroll,you would have to scroll to see the enlarged image if it is larger than the div. When I don't see the overflow-x property to scroll, I can view the enlarged image on top of everything else like I want to but all the other thumbnails are also visible. Here is a code snippet to show what I've done.

HTML

```
<div id="example1">
<h1>This is an example</h1>
<h2>Car 1</h2>
<div class="scroll">
<div id="example1_car1">
<a class="thumb" href="#"><img src="car1.jpg" alt="car1" height="200" width="251"><span>   <img src="car1.jpg" alt="car1"></span></a>
<a class="thumb" href="#"><img src="car2.jpg" alt="car2" height="200" width="251"><span><img src="car2.jpg" alt="car2"></span></a>
<a class="thumb" href="#"><img src="car3.jpg" alt="car3" height="200" width="251"><span><img src="car3.jpg" alt="car3"></span></a>
</div><!--example1_car1-->
</div><!--example1_scroll-->
<h2>Car 2</h2>
<div class="scroll">
<div id="example1_car2">
<a class="thumb" href="#"><img src="car1.jpg" alt="car1" height="200" width="251"><span><img src="car1.jpg" alt="car1"></span></a>
<a class="thumb" href="#"><img src="car2.jpg" alt="car2" height="200" width="251"><span><img src="car2.jpg" alt="car2"></span></a>
<a class="thumb" href="#"><img src="car3.jpg" alt="car3" height="200" width="251"><span>  <img src="car3.jpg" alt="car3"></span></a>
</div><!--example1_car2-->
</div><!--example2_scroll-->
</div><!--example1-->

CSS
#example1_car1,#example1_car2,.scroll{
   position:relative;
}

#example1_car1, #example1_car2
{
  width:2400px;
  height:200px;
  z-index:0
}

.scroll
{
   width:800px;
   height:210px;

   overflow-x:scroll;
   z-index:0;
}

.thumb img {
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:3px;
    float:left;
    zindex:-1;
}
.thumb span {
    position: relative;/*absolute;*/
    display:none;
}
.thumb:hover, .thumb:hover span {
    display:inline;
    top:0; left: 0px;
    /*z-index:1;*/
    z-index:10;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the enlarged image appear on top of/outside of the scrollable region, it will have to actually be outside of it.

To make the enlarged image appear *outside*, when hovering over a thumbnail that is *inside* of the scrollable region, you will need to use JavaScript on top of your HTML and CSS.

Here's [an example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xAeLp/1/), in which I haven't changed your HTML structure. Instead I used jQuery to clone the enlarged image outside of the scrollable region and append it to the #example1 div, when you hover over a thumbnail.

JavaScript portion:

```
$('.thumb').hover(
    function(){
        var thumb = $(this).children('img');
        var large = $(this).find('span>img').clone();
        $('#example1').append(large);
        large.addClass('enlargedImg');
        large.css({
            'top': thumb.offset().top,
            'left': thumb.offset().left
        });
    },
    function(){
        $('.enlargedImg').remove();
    }
);
```

I used the thumb image's offset() values to position the enlarged image directly on top of it. You'll probably want to move it a bit but hopefully this is enough to get you started.